# [thread][wab-App] static thread java

Tags: multithreading, web-applications

i want to know if this would allow me to get always the same thread when i redirect ?
thanks for ur help!

```
class A extends Servlet{
 private static DLTarThread t;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    if(((String)session.getAttribute("start")).equals("ok")){
    this.t = new DLTarThread(download,source,Destination);
    t.start();
    }


    while(t.isAlive()){
        resp.sendRedirect("/Sn1MdpOutil/TelechargementBigAvismob");
    }
```